# What is the difference between app engine and cloud endpoints when developing with Android studio?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to do this for a while, but I'm confused as to the difference between the two applications.

I know that endpoints helps you expose an API and generate the client libraries that allow you to interact with your Android app.

But in the examples, it seems as though endpoints is the only code you write for the backend at all.

I thought that app engine was what the actual application ran on - that is, do I need a separate project with the app engine backend, then my android studio project with the Android app and the endpoints API, or does writing the endpoints API also serve as the app engine backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoints backend API is just a piece of a GAE app functionality.

If you only have that functionality in your app you can extend it by adding the desired stuff to the existing `app.yaml` file (and the related app code), you don't **have to** create a new app. Especially if the endpoints functionality and the additional desired functionality are related.

You can also add endpoints backend support to an existing GAE app by merging the endpoints backend `app.yaml` content into the existing app's `app.yaml` file and adding the class file and API server file to the app's code.

Comment: Thank you - that caveat about app.yaml really pulled it all together for me. The Android endpoints tutorial is kind of vague about how Endpoints ties into App Engine - it referred to it as "App Engine with Endpoints" so discretizing the system was hard for me.